# Remove duplicated data from AB BA

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I want to remove data if AB and BA is the same

This is my code:

```
DB::table(DB::raw('tenant_db.sales_data as b'))
            ->selectRaw('a.product_id as product_id, b.product_id as bought_with, count(*) as times_bought_together')
            ->leftJoin(DB::raw('tenant_db.sales_data as a'), function ($join){
                $join->on('a.sale_id', '=', 'b.sale_id');
                $join->on('a.product_id', '<>', 'b.product_id');
            })
            ->havingRaw('SUM(a.qty) >= SUM(b.qty)')
            ->groupBy('a.product_id', 'b.product_id')
            ->orderBy('times_bought_together', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

I want the most bought item on the right side thats why I did this

```
            ->havingRaw('SUM(a.qty) >= SUM(b.qty)')
```

If i use ">=" it will show 2 times if its the same QTY, but I only want it 1 time, So if AB is the same as BA I want it only 1 time to show not 2 times

Output

```
Product_id          Bought_with         times_bought_together'

52                      24                          3
24                      52                          3
```

Comment: why did you use laravel if you don't want use eloquent? what's your models name?

Comment: Because I use Datatables yarja, otherwise I can't filter them